# Ubuntu Read Only File System On Almost Every Boot Even After FSCK

Tags: fsck

I'm a newbie web developer using 14.04. I've been having a 'read only file system' problem after almost every boot. If I don't have the problem, I eventually get it after a few hours.

I followed the troubleshooting steps mentioned in the other posts, such as running fsck, e2fsck from a live usb. Terminal says it solved the issue, but when I boot, it goes back to read only file system. I've done the short disk self-test which says OK, though the full self-test fails.

I formatted my hard disk and installed Windows a few months ago and it ran fine.

I reinstalled 14.04 and I noticed the problem became very frequent after I installed Chrome. So I replaced it with Chromium which lessened its frequency, but recently it has been become very frequent again. I need Chrome / Chromium to troubleshoot websites.

Is there any solution to this ? I am thinking of formatting to 15.10 just to see if the problem will be solved.

Comment: Sounds like you need a new hard drive.

Comment: If the self test failed, then that is a strong indicator that the drive is indeed dieing.  Posting the specific details would of course be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted my hard disk and installed 15.10. This time I didn't install Chrome or Chromium and my computer has been ok since.